# How to take multiple variables from URL and insert it to a MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, variables

I am trying to make a database. I am using php. What I want to happen is to go. domain.com/save.php?var1=100&var2=200&var3=300 and so on for 7 variables. One variable would be text, 6 are numbers, 1 is auto incrementing. I am getting very confused. I have the first example here (https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_multiple.asp) working. I'm also wondering about protecting from SQL injection and such. Thanks!

Edit: One variable is auto incrementing.

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and [help/on-topic]

Comment: Yeah... people reading this must be "very confused" too...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in PHP you can get parameters from a URL using the global variable $_GET, for example if you have the next url:

http://www.example.com/index.php?name=john

You could get the name parameter so:

```
echo $_GET['name'];
```

There are more global variables in PHP, for example **$_REQUEST**, **$_GET** and **$_POST**.

- **$_GET** hold the parameters received through GET (URL parameters).
- **$_POST** hold the parameters received through POST (forms).
- **$_REQUEST** hold both GET and POST parameters.

More info in [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)